# Placemark in kml maps is visible with the check box inactive

Tags: html, google-maps, maps, kml, google-earth

I have a malfunction with my project map. When I upload the map in the code I don't want the folders to show up and they are unchecked and invisible but there are still a lot of points on the map....What is the problem?

this is the web page 
http://mio.com.co/mapa/mapa.html,

and here is the kml (sorry for not posting the code as it is too long)

http://mio.com.co/mapa/kml/sept.kml

Comment: Seems to be working the way you want.  Have you tried clearing the browser cache?  What browser are you using?

Comment: It is a browser specific problem.  I see it in Chrome, but not in Firefox. I get javascript errors in all browswers, including IE, where the map controls don't show up.

Comment: but the problem is the placemark non hiden when the kml charge
pd: is visible in all brwosers...

Comment: charge...and is pd (pos data) : sorry for my english

Comment: I assume "pos data" is position data.  Are you changing the KML?  Or the position of the map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want things not to be visible, the correct way to do it in KML is to set:

```
<visibility>0</visibility>
```

[KML Reference](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#visibility)

Don't know why your version doesn't work (I suspect it has to do with the way you are loading it, but I am not an expert on Lance Dyas' GeoXml-V3), [this version (based off the simple example on the project home page)](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_dyasdesigns_com_geoxml_closed_sept.html) seems to do the right thing.

Comment: Not sure why the is, see the simple example I added to my answer.

Comment: hi @geocodezip
i try to copy your map, to rebuild mine, but when upload the html in my server it dosnt show only the map but the kml is no working, you have a zip of the proyect? or a tutorial?